# Segmentation Fault with declared variables C++

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am trying to create a node class. The node class has two variables: an int, and a pointer to another node. Here are my node constructors. I found on another stack overflow that in order to allocate memory for values, you need to include a "new ... " phrase.

```
Node::Node() {
    next = new Node;
}

Node::Node(int new_num) {
    num = new_num;
    next = new Node;
}
```

I am using a method called AssignArray which takes an array of ints and turns that into a linked list of nodes. Parts of it work, except when I try to use the setNext method on my node. The setNext method is just a regular setter.

```
void Node::setNext(Node* new_next) {
    next = new_next;
}

Node* Node::AssignArray(int list[], int i, int size) {
    if (i == size) {
        return NULL;
    }
    else {
        Node new_node(list[i]);
        i++;
        new_node.setNext(new_node.AssignArray(list, i , size));
        return &new_node;
    }

}
```

Here is my main function so far:

```
int main() {

    int nums1[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int nums2[] = {1,3,5,7,9};
    
    Node node1 = Node();
    int nums1_size = sizeof(nums1)/sizeof(nums1[0]);
    node1.AssignArray(nums1, 0, nums1_size);
```

Comment: When you make a node, your constructor makes another node, causing an infinite loop of node creation.

Comment: `return &new_node` returns a pointer to a local object. That object ceases to exist when the function returns, so the function always returns an invalid pointer.

Comment: *"include a "new ... " phrase"* is outdated advice. See `std::make_unique` if you need to dynamically create objects. `new` has almost no legitimate use in C++ anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that you're calling `setNext` with the return value from `AssignArray`, which you return as `&new_node`, which is a pointer to a local `Node` that you allocated on the stack. As soon as the function returns, the stack unwinds and that `Node` instance ceases to exist, leaving the pointer dangling.

At the very least you should be doing:

```
Node* new_node = new Node(list[i]);
...
return new_node;
```

But I also feel like we're missing some things here. It would be nice to see the definition of `Node`. And how is this constructor not producing a stack overflow?

```
Node::Node() {
    next = new Node;
}
```

In the constructor you do `new Node` which will call this same constructor again... which will call the constructor again...

Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

I think new node added on constructor while infinite loop through itself.

```
Node::Node() {
next = new Node;
```

}

It will be better to avoid this type of calling.